# Dont know how to simply solve this determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$
\det\begin{pmatrix}
-2a & a + b & a + c\\
b+a & -2b & b+c\\
c+a & c+b & -2c
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I solved this determinant and gave me $4(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ but I've done it by adding $((b+c)/2a)*\text{line 1}$ to $\text{line 2}$ and $((c+a)/2a)*\text{line 1}$ to $\text{line 3}$.
I still don't see another way of getting 2 zeros on a line or column that can be done by simple additions and subtractions instead of multiplying by variables like I did.

Thank you!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you did (unless $a=0$).

Comment: Ik but it seems kinda complicated

Comment: For expressions it doesnt really matter if i divide (by a) but still it feels knid of forced to multiply like that

Comment: You could use the [rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) and then factorize. This is not so complicated as it might appear.

Comment: Yes but still there will be many calculations. I am asking if there is a neat solution to this.

Comment: Check these: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2782450/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2788320/42969.

Comment: Thanks, so it turns out this determinant has in fact some calculations...